# Convert character to lowerCamelCase in R

Tags: regex, r, character, gsub

I have character vector which looks like this:

```
x <- c("cult", "brother sister relationship", "word title")
```

And I want to convert it to the `lowerCamelCase` style looking like this:

```
c("cult", "brotherSisterRelationship", "wordTitle")
```

I played around with `gsub`, `gregexpr`, `strplit`, `regmatches` and many other functions, but couldn't get a grip.

Especially two spaces in a character seem to be difficult to handle.

Maybe someone here has an idea how to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
> x <- c("cult", "brother sister relationship", "word title")
> gsub(" ([^ ])", "\\U\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "cult"                      "brotherSisterRelationship"
[3] "wordTitle"
```

Quoting from [pattern matching and replacement](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

> For perl = TRUE only, it can also contain "\U" or "\L" to convert the
>   rest of the replacement to upper or lower case and "\E" to end case
>   conversion.

Comment: I really have no idea what goes on here, but thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

A non-`base` alternative:

```
library(R.utils)
toCamelCase(x, capitalize = FALSE)
# [1] "cult"                      "brotherSisterRelationship" "wordTitle"
```